# Possible to run Visual Studio 2010 RC and Visual C# 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 RC. I want to install Visual C# 2008 because XNA Game Studio needs it to be installed. Can I run them side-by-side?

Comment: You can install both and fire both up at the same time if you choose, if that is your question. When all else fails, just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  You can install VS 2010 RC and VS 2008 side-by-side with no issues.  I have both installed on my system, and have had no problems at all.

Be aware, though, that opening a solution in VS 2010 RC will convert your solution and projects to the VS 2010 format, which is not backwards compatible with VS 2008.  If you migrate an app to VS 2010, it will permanently change it.